# Problem in upload wordpress with net2ftb

Tags: uploads

I create a site with free host by auto setting and upload wordpress on it. Now i want to upload a module that i write. But i don't know how to do it ?
I hear that i can do it by "net2ftp"
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your software is not good solution for your problem. Use FileZilla to upload wp on a Server.